# In matlab trying to plot multiple trajectories in time simultaneously

Tags: matlab, animation, plot, 3d

I am trying to plot multiple oscillators animated wrt. time, such that they are animated "simultaneously" in order to follow them side by side.
I am able to plot each point separately, but I would like for each oscillator to have a line connected between its respective point in the animation.

It has proven difficult and I have tried using "addpoints(h,x,y,z)" (it worked for single trajectories) but each connection naturally becomes disjointed after each oscillator step and I am at a bit of a loss as to what to try.

The loop itself looks like this, with t being time, osc being the oscillator number and sin(y) being its position at a given time for each oscillator.

```
for t = 1:tlen
    for osc = 1:5
        plot3(t,osc,sin(y(osc,t)),'k.-')
        drawnow;
    end
end
```

Here 'k' makes it black '-' should have been a line but is ignored and '.' makes dots

and 'k-' is likewise ignored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure I get your problem exactly, but would this be a solution?

```
Num_Oscillators = 5;
for t = 1:tlen
    figure(1);clf;
    for iOscillator = 1:Num_Oscillators
        plot3(1:t,iOscillator*ones(1,t),sin(y(iOscillator,1:t)),'k-.' );
        hold on;
    end
    drawnow;
end
```

This requires y to be written such that it can take a whole vector of time samples and return a vector of oscillator positions (if it cannot be written in this way you need to cache your old values).

If this version makes the screen flicker (it will on older versions of Matlab), try this instead (it might also be a bit faster):

```
figure(1);clf;
Num_Oscillators = 5;
plot_handles = cell(1,Num_Oscillators);
for iOscillator = 1:Num_Oscillators
    plot_handles{iOscillator} = plot3(inf,inf,inf,'k.-');hold on;
end
for t = 1:tlen
    for iOscillator = 1:Num_Oscillators
        set(plot_handles{iOscillator},'XData',1:t,'YData',iOscillator*ones(1,t),'ZData',sin(y(iOscillator,1:t)));

    end
    drawnow;
end
```

With this simple mockup example data

```
tlen = 100;
y = @(osc,t) 2*pi/tlen*osc*t;
```

it generates this output (animating them as they go):

[image: 3D plot of oscillators]

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to look at the problem, it was exactly what I was looking for :)
Fortunately, I have a newer version of matlab from the university and the first one will suffice but I am impressed you also included one for an older version.